# Prevent cex from scaling with the correlation coefficient in chart.Correlation()

Tags: r, correlation

I'm trying to plot a huge matrix of correlation coefficients, and currently, my plot looks like this:
[image: Notice that some cells are missing correlation coefficients]

Notice that some cells are missing correlation coefficients (ignore for now that lack of symmetry of the plot, unless you happen know why that's the case, too). I believe that the values are not, in fact, missing, but simply too small to appear, because they are scaled by the value of their correlation coefficient.

Looking at the documentation for chart.Correlation(), I was able to find a function from which much of the content of chart.Correlation() was modeled:

```
panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits=2, prefix="", cex.cor)
{
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
    r <- abs(cor(x, y))
    txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits=digits)[1]
    txt <- paste(prefix, txt, sep="")
    if(missing(cex.cor)) cex <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)    
    test <- cor.test(x,y)
    # borrowed from printCoefmat
    Signif <- symnum(test$p.value, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE,
                  cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1),
                  symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))

    text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex * r)
    text(.8, .8, Signif, cex=cex, col=2)
}
pairs(USJudgeRatings[,c(2:3,6,1,7)], lower.panel=panel.smooth, upper.panel=panel.cor)
```

If I change:

```
text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex * r)
```

To:

```
text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = 0.8)
```

I get roughly the effect I'm looking for. The problem is that I have no idea how to change this parameter using chart.Correlation() itself. Does issue this make sense?

Comment: FWIW, the part of that code that isn't part of `example(pairs)` appears to come from http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/Correlation_Matrix,137

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hack that modifies the function to allow what you want.  This adds a user-settable exponent argument to the function that allows you to change the `cex` value to `cex*[correlation]^cex.cor.scale`.

It spits out warnings because of the way `...` is handled; they're annoying but harmless.

It would probably be best to contact the maintainer and ask them if they'd be willing to enhance the function, or start creating your own modified version of the package.

**edit**: slightly more robust changes to the relevant lines

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
## turn the function into a character string
tmpstr <- deparse(chart.Correlation)
## modify the relevant lines
panelcorline <- grep("^ *panel.cor",tmpstr)
tmpstr[panelcorline] <- paste(tmpstr[panelcorline],"cex.cor.scale=1,")
rscaleline <- grep("^ *text\\(0.5",tmpstr)
tmpstr[rscaleline] <- gsub("cex \\* r","cex*r^cex.cor.scale",tmpstr[rscaleline])
## convert back to a function (don't mask the original function)
my.chart.Correlation <- eval(parse(text=tmpstr))
```

Test it out:

```
data(managers)
chart.Correlation(managers[,1:8], histogram=TRUE, pch="+")
## no scaling
my.chart.Correlation(managers[,1:8], histogram=TRUE, pch="+",cex.cor.scale=0)
## enhanced scaling
my.chart.Correlation(managers[,1:8], histogram=TRUE, pch="+",cex.cor.scale=2)
```

Comment: Ben Bolker, thanks so much for this! It seems like there's an error when I try to run either of these lines:
    ## no scaling
    my.chart.Correlation(managers[,1:8], histogram=TRUE, pch="+",cex.cor.scale=0)
    ## enhanced scaling
    my.chart.Correlation(managers[,1:8], histogram=TRUE, pch="+",cex.cor.scale=2)

The normal chart looks brilliant, but the other two yield a correlation map with one cell...
Thanks again for the hack! I never would have been able to figure something like that out on my own.

Comment: what are the results of `deparse(chart.Correlation)[c(4,18)]`?  do they look like lines that can be sensibly replaced by those above?  Are you using the latest version (PerformanceAnalytics 1.0.4.4) (see `sessionInfo()`)?  This hack will be very sensitive to changes in the underlying function ...

Comment: They look like the ones you're trying to replace. And PerformanceAnalytics is up-to-date:
    > ## convert back to a function (don't mask the original function)
    > my.chart.Correlation<-eval(parse(text=tmpstr))
    Error in parse(text = tmpstr) : <text>:4:85: unexpected input
    3:     x = checkData(R, method = "matrix")
    4: panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, prefix = "", use = "pairwise.complete.obs", ¬

    Error in text.default(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex * r^cex.cor.scale) : 
      object 'cex.cor.scale' not found

Comment: Sorry that I can't make that look better in a comment. There seem to be two problems: 1)the unexpected input (so, maybe a typo from copying and pasting?) and 2) it doesn't like cex.cor.scale (which wasn't in the original function)...Thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind! I just noticed your edit, and it worked! But I'm still curious above that comma from the previous comment.

Comment: it has a comma because that line ends in the middle of the list of function argument, which continues onto the next line ...